# What does "subsonic Fluger impact delivery dart" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It's from "The Lost World. Jurassic Park". The character of Richard Schiff describes his rifle. "Lindstradt air rifle. Fires a subsonic Fluger impact delivery dart".
This line drives me crazy. Especially "fluger" or "fluger-impact". I couldn't find any definition in the Internet. I think it's a name, but even though it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Fluger is a proper name, presumably the inventor or manufacturer of the type of dart. The dart is propelled by a burst of air and flies at less than the speed of sound; upon impact with its target, it delivers a dose of fast-acting poison, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.

Notice that "Fluger" has a capital, indicating it is proper noun. It probably refers to the fictional company that makes the darts.

To give a sense of realism, the author drops these little details in. It gives an impression that his characters have depth. He is showing that Schiff is an expert in guns and darts, since he knows the brand of darts that he is using. It is part of the character development that the author is doing.

Here is the [quote in context](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ejR-38YEG6sC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=flugar-impact%20delivery%20dart&source=bl&ots=swp59cgTb7&sig=VbT8u3AFROZJ9O9GCG_40Ir12mM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1yaWRvPDNAhUmC8AKHfflCpMQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=flugar-impact%20delivery%20dart&f=false), and a [wiki page about the gun](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Lindstradt_Air_Gun)